# Finding points around closest point of linestring ordered by distance using PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, performance, spatial-query, geography-data-type

I am looking for a way to improve my solution of the following problem in PostgreSQL (using PostGIS).

Given a point A, a Linestring B and a series of (yellow) points spread all over the area in which A and B are, **I would like to return the points around C ordered by distance**. C is the closest point of A in B. Bellow there is a simple diagram to roughly explain the layout of the of aforementioned elements:

[image: Simple diagram]

What I have so far looks like the following query:

```
SELECT id, location FROM yellow_points WHERE
    ST_DWithin(
        location,
        ST_ClosestPoint(B::geometry, A::geometry)::geography,
        blue_radius_in_meters
    )
    ORDER BY ST_Distance(ST_ClosestPoint(B::geometry, A::geometry)::geography, location)
```

Where `location` is on geography type. However, as seen, I am using twice the `ST_ClosestPoint` function, which gives me a bad impact on the performance I presume. The results are around 3ms without the order by and around 35ms with the order by. As the order is important here, I would like to know how to reuse the `ST_ClosestPoint` by defining it once.

**Update**:

As request, here are some `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` for the queries, one with the subselect, as suggested in the comments, and another without as I am originally doing. Besides, it goes with some data that looks like the data I query with:

```
SELECT name, location FROM myschema.yellow_points WHERE
    ST_DWithin(
        location,
        ST_ClosestPoint(
            ST_GeomFromEWKT('SRID=4326;LINESTRING(2.3369979858398438 48.87363508768185, 2.3291873931884766 48.861665678191514, 2.3048973083496094 48.861326879656716, 2.2911643981933594 48.85138776898278)'),
            ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(2.316567, 48.855222),4326)
        )::geography,
        10000
    )
    ORDER BY ST_Distance(
        ST_ClosestPoint(
            ST_GeomFromEWKT('SRID=4326;LINESTRING(2.3369979858398438 48.87363508768185, 2.3291873931884766 48.861665678191514, 2.3048973083496094 48.861326879656716, 2.2911643981933594 48.85138776898278)'),
            ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(2.316567, 48.855222),4326)
        )::geography,
        location
    );

Sort  (cost=8.93..8.94 rows=1 width=50) (actual time=57.452..58.567 rows=12294 loops=1)
   Sort Key: (_st_distance('0101000020E6100000F60A4C74268802409785BB40456E4840'::geography, location, '0'::double precision, true))
   Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 1914kB
   ->  Index Scan using yellow_points_source_id_location_index on yellow_points  (cost=0.28..8.92 rows=1 width=50) (actual time=0.219..52.320 rows=12294 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (location && '0101000020E6100000F60A4C74268802409785BB40456E4840'::geography)
         Filter: (('0101000020E6100000F60A4C74268802409785BB40456E4840'::geography && _st_expand(location, '10000'::double precision)) AND _st_dwithin(location, '0101000020E6100000F60A4C74268802409785BB40456E4840'::geography, '10000'::double precision, true))
         Rows Removed by Filter: 3277
 Planning time: 0.281 ms
 Execution time: 59.508 ms
```

And the alternative way with the subselect:

```
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT name, location, ST_ClosestPoint(
                ST_GeomFromEWKT('SRID=4326;LINESTRING(2.3369979858398438 48.87363508768185, 2.3291873931884766 48.861665678191514, 2.3048973083496094 48.861326879656716, 2.2911643981933594 48.85138776898278)')
                ,
                ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(2.316567, 48.855222),4326)
            )::geography as point FROM myschema.yellow_points) AS r WHERE
    ST_DWithin(r.point, r.location, 10000)
    ORDER BY ST_Distance(r.point, r.location);

 Sort  (cost=8.93..8.94 rows=1 width=50) (actual time=59.966..61.034 rows=12294 loops=1)
   Sort Key: (_st_distance('0101000020E6100000F60A4C74268802409785BB40456E4840'::geography, yellow_points.location, '0'::double precision, true))
   Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 2637kB
   ->  Index Scan using yellow_points_source_id_location_index on yellow_points  (cost=0.28..8.92 rows=1 width=50) (actual time=0.253..53.344 rows=12294 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (location && '0101000020E6100000F60A4C74268802409785BB40456E4840'::geography)
         Filter: (('0101000020E6100000F60A4C74268802409785BB40456E4840'::geography && _st_expand(location, '10000'::double precision)) AND _st_dwithin('0101000020E6100000F60A4C74268802409785BB40456E4840'::geography, location, '10000'::double precision, true))
         Rows Removed by Filter: 3277
 Planning time: 2.132 ms
 Execution time: 62.466 ms
```

Comment: could you add explain analyze output to question. 
What i would try (move group by outside) : 
SELECT * from 
(select id, location,  ST_ClosestPoint(B::geometry, A::geometry)::geography as point from ....) AS r GROUP BY st_distance(r.point, r.location )

Comment: What version of postgis are you using? There has been a large improvement in 2.1 for calculating distance in geography (see manual on ST_Distance). Still, geography will be slower than calculations on a cartesian grid, so I would consider projecting to a local grid first (unless you have world-wide data).

Comment: 35 milliseconds isn't an awful result time with all those casts *and* an `ORDER BY`.Please edit the quesion to specify how many rows are returned and include the `ANALYZE` output for the query. The DBA SE group might be more appropriate for questions about use of `WITH` and/or virtual tables.

Comment: @Vince thank you for your insight. As I am pretty new with PostGIS/Postgres, I will take a look into the ANALYZE so that I can better see what is going on with the query. By no means I have said that the 35ms is awfull, but a newbie, I guess I'd probably doing something not good here. Thank you.

Comment: I meant `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`. If your results are under 100ms, it's unlikely "something not good" is involved.

Comment: @tilt, the version I am using is 2.1.4. So the improvements you have mentioned are probably considered here. The data is indeed global. Thanks for the insights!

Comment: @Vince, I have added  the EXPLAIN ANALYZE to the question, together with the subquery alternative suggested by simplexio.